# How to sum variables values RUBY

Tags: ruby

First, I am new to ruby so please be gentle hehe.

I have a school project where the assignment is to calculate the total cost of a project. In my code, the user is giving the variables some input. Later on, I want to show the total of all these inputs. (the inputs is number)
So basically I need to add them up and it needs to give me a sum of them.

How do I do that?

Hope you amazing people can help me:)

Here is my code:

```
    file = File.new("testing.txt", "a")

class Project 

  def call_acc

    prompt = "> "
    puts
    puts "What is the salary for an accountant?"
    print prompt

    while @accountant = gets.chomp

      if !/\A\d+\z/.match(@accountant)
        puts
        puts "Error: Only use numbers, please try again"
        print prompt

      else
        break
      end
    end
  end


  def call_dev

    prompt = "> "
    puts
    puts "What is the salary for an developer?"
    print prompt

    while @developer = gets.chomp

      if !/\A\d+\z/.match(@developer)
        puts
        puts "Error: Only use numbers, please try again"
        print prompt

      else
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def call_mana

    prompt = "> "
    puts
    puts "What is the salary for the top management?"
    print prompt

    while @management = gets.chomp

      if !/\A\d+\z/.match(@management)
        puts
        puts "Error: Only use numbers, please try again"
        print prompt

      else
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def call_office

    prompt = "> "
    puts
    puts "What is the total office rent for the project?"
    print prompt

    while @office = gets.chomp

      if !/\A\d+\z/.match(@office)
        puts
        puts "Error: Only use numbers, please try again"
        print prompt

      else
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def call_lunch

    prompt = "> "
    puts
    puts "What is the daily cost for lunch per person?"
    print prompt

    while @lunch = gets.chomp

      if !/\A\d+\z/.match(@lunch)
        puts
        puts "Error: Only use numbers, please try again"
        print prompt

      else
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def call_utilites

    prompt = "> "
    puts
    puts "What is the total cost for utilites (internet, subscriptions etc)?"
    print prompt

    while @utilites = gets.chomp

      if !/\A\d+\z/.match(@utilites)
        puts
        puts "Error: Only use numbers, please try again"
        print prompt

      else
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def call_show

    prompt = "> "
    puts "____________________________________"
    puts
    puts "Is this information correct?"
    puts
    puts "Accountant salary (per hour): #{@accountant}kr\nDevelepor salary (per hour): #{@developer}kr\nTop management salary (per hour): #{@management}kr"
    puts
    puts "Total rent cost of office space: #{@office}kr\nLunch per person per day: #{@lunch}kr\nTotal cost of utilites #{@utilites}kr"
    puts
    puts "____________________________________"
    puts "Yes or No"
    print prompt 

    while user_imput = gets.chomp.upcase 

      case user_imput

      when "YES"
        file = File.new("testing.txt", "a")
        file.puts("Account salary: #{@accountant}kr\nDeveloper selary: #{@developer}kr\nTop management salary #{@management}kr\nTotal rent cost: #{@office}kr\nLunch per person #{@lunch}kr\nUtilites cost #{@utilites}kr")
        file.close
        puts
        puts "The information has now been stored"
        puts "____________________________________"
        break
      when "NO"
        puts
        puts "The information has not been stored. Exiting application"
        puts "____________________________________"
        abort
      else 
        puts 
        puts "Please either write Yes or No"
        print prompt
      end
    end
  end

  def call_total

    prompt = "> "
    puts
    puts "________Your information_______"
    puts 
    puts "Accountant salary (per hour): #{@accountant}kr\nDevelepor salary (per hour): #{@developer}kr\nTop management salary (per hour): #{@management}kr"
    puts
    puts "Total rent cost of office space: #{@office}kr\nLunch per person per day: #{@lunch}kr\nTotal cost of utilites #{@utilites}kr"
    puts 
    puts "________Total cost of project________"
    puts
    puts ?????????@accountant + @developer??????????????+
    puts

  end

  project = Project.new
  require 'io/console'
  select = 0
  prompt = "> "
  puts 
  puts 
  puts "Welcome to KEA"
  puts "____________________________________"

  loop do(select != 7)
    puts
    puts "Press 1 to calculate"
    puts "____________________________________"
    select = STDIN.getch.to_i

    if (select == 1)
      project.call_acc
      project.call_dev
      project.call_mana
      project.call_office
      project.call_lunch
      project.call_utilites
      project.call_show
      project.call_total

      break

    else
      puts 
      puts "Invalid input. Please try again"
      puts "____________________________________"

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error or some unexpected output?

Comment: _"the user is giving the variables some input"_ – could you show the code that collects input from the user and assigns it to the variables?

Comment: What is `@accountant`? What is `@developer`? We don't know how to fix your issue, if we don't know how to reproduce it. You also haven't shown how the user makes an input.

Comment: My guess, as this is the most common mistake beginners make, is that somewhere you're doing `gets.chomp` - which stores the data as a **String**. You need to covert this value into a number - e.g. an `Integer`, by calling `.to_i`.

Comment: Added the code now

Comment: Your question is _"how to sum variables"_ – that sounds quite simple. Do you really think that you have to post 200 lines of code for a working example?

Comment: Yes I know. But I want it to be user-friendly, which is one of the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question stated in title:

```
numbers =
  loop.inject([]) do |acc, _|
    val = gets.to_i
    break acc unless val > 0
    acc << val
  end

numbers.reduce(:+)
```